# How to find unused or least used executable names?

Tags: command-line

Imagine that you want to make a new command line tool and you want to assure that your executable which will be in PATH has a very low chance of clashing with something else that already exist?

How would you investigate this? is there any database of executable names that we could query?

While my main focus is on Unix/Linux, it would be nice to have a general view so you could come up with a generic and simple name?

Answer (score 1):

Search google for "mynewcooltool.exe" - if you get no sensible matches (automated exe and dll selling sites do not count), then it is yours :)

At least for Windows world - but because best unix utilites are ported, then this covers broader area than just Windows.